# A word to describe knowing something completely

Tags: single-word-requests

We just can not think of a word to describe this situation where you understand something completely. There is nothing you do not know about it.

If anyone knows or has something close then that would be great.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Comprehend* and *fathom* are fine candidates, I'll just throw in *attain enlightenment* for good measure.

**Edit:** oh, and how about *grok* ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grok), [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grok))?

Answer (score 5):

**fathom**, though more often used in the negative (*he could hardly fathom...*), means to “comprehend after much thought”. **comprehend** also has this same connotation.

Expressions such as **puzzle out** or **get to the bottom of** have the sense of understanding completely, but also mean it was figured out (i.e. that knowledge is recent). It may or may not be adequate for your use case.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/comprehend), *to comprehend* is "to understand or grasp fully and thoroughly".

Answer (score 3):

I would use *omniscient*.

> The story is told by an omniscient narrator.

From the NOAD:

> omniscient /ɑmˈnɪʃənt/
>   adjective
>   knowing everything

Comment: A bit too strong, IMHO. Omniscient means "knowing *everything*" rather than "knowing something completely".

Answer (score 3):

Informally, the term *guru* might apply here.

> Struggling with his spreadsheet, Bob
>   knew where to turn: Alice was the Excel *guru* in the office.

Answer (score 3):

I feel obliged to add *grok*. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grok):

> Grok means to understand so thoroughly that the observer becomes a part of the observed—to merge, blend, intermarry, lose identity in group experience.
>
> When you claim to 'grok' some knowledge or technique, you are asserting that you have not merely learned it in a detached instrumental way but that it has become part of you, part of your identity.

Example:  It took me forever to grok recursive functions.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking as someone who has worked for an educational testing company, the students who demonstrated the best understanding of an essay topic were described as having a *thorough* understanding.

Answer (score 2):

You could use *Master*, a term used in the trades.

In order of least skilled to most skilled:
Novice/Apprentice ---> Journeyman -------> Master

Mastery is also used for cognitive processes: mastered a language, mastered algebra.

A slang term is *Whiz*, that's likely short for *Wizard*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the situation ever arises. *The (world's) leading authority on* a subject is perhaps a safer concept, but who decides who that is?

I couldn't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is not the word, but reading your question it seemed to me you were describing a moment or a situation more-so than you were a person,

in which case there is a beautiful German word which is *aha-Erlibnes*,  meaning;

(literally) an "aha-experience". An experience which gives a sudden insight.

or one could say *epiphany*;

a moment of sudden revelation or insight.

Answer (score 0):

Omniscient - Knowing everything 
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/omniscient