# What is the word to describe "the gaining of full control over an ability or power you already have"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

For example, a Jedi is born with powers, but must learn how to control them in order to use them. What's the one best word for this?

> I have _ _ _ my power.

The word is in the back of my head but I can't pull it out. It also means to have a full understanding of something.

> I _ _ _ the way the world works.

Comment: Keeping with the nerdiness, how about "[grok](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grok)" =)

Comment: @jadarnel27 I actually had no idea the word "grok" existed until asking this question. hehe. It's valid, but I'd like a general term so anyone can understand it. So far, I think "harnessed" is the best word.

Comment: Related to the second part: [A word to describe knowing something completely](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9902/a-word-to-describe-knowing-something-completely)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could say that you have [*harnessed*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/harness) your power. Or, you have *unleashed its full potential*.

Comment: Yes yes yes!! Its along those lines... What other words can you think of similar to having harnessed?

Comment: @JoePea Capture, control, summon.

Comment: What about a word along the lines of "to the finest level of understanding"?

Comment: @JoePea Grasp, perceive, fathom, comprehend.

Comment: @JoePea I would still go with harnessed, maybe mastered.

Comment: No, this is the wrong word.  To harness a power is to make use of it for some purpose.  It does not imply mastery or full control.  For example, solar panels allow us to harness solar energy for electricity.

Comment: @Joe-Pea An hour is way too soon to accept an answer. The person with the right answer might be in bed! Give it a day or two, so that everyone in the community gets to answer and upvote, and the cream can rise to the top.

Comment: Learn to wait, the young Padawan must. _Harnessed_ will he have, the full potential of English.SE.

Comment: Neither of these words/phrases implies **control**.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson This is the first word that came to my mind, and I think that if you have power, but are unable to use it, then once you *are* able to use it, you have harnessed your potential power.

Comment: But the question specifically mentions **control**. I can **harness** the water coming out of a firehose, doesn't mean I have **any** control, much less complete **control** over it, and thus **mastery** or **realized**, which is the more correct terms for the question. The Solar panel example in another comment is another good example of why this should not be the answer.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson See [definition 7.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/harness) As well, look at the synonyms.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't say anything about **complete** control, which is implied in the context of the question *"It also means to have a full understanding of something"* and the words **mastery** or **realized** imply this **completeness**.

Comment: Read for comprehension, the word **complete** is all my comments as well as others, and it is in implied in the question as well. *"It also means to have a full understanding of something"*

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry. Your bolding of control directly beside complete distract's one's eyes.

Answer (score 126):

I think  "mastered" or  "mastery" could be the word you're looking for.  Perhaps "fulfilled", especially if you want to say one has fulfilled their potential.

Comment: For reference, the sentence could be "I have mastered my power" or "I have mastery over my power". Personally, I prefer the second option.

Comment: @Hallainzil +1 for the examples, although I personally prefer the first.

Comment: More flowery: I have come into the fullness of my power. Yoda does Heinlein: The way the world works, I now grok in fullness.

Comment: Although this answer is accurate, I still like "harnessed" better for some reason. "Harnessed" is more in terms of being able to grasp or contain something. "I have learnt how to 'contain' my power in order to use it as I please," or "I have discovered how to grasp my powers in order use them as I please."

Answer (score 44):

Perhaps *realize*: "He realized his full power."

Comment: When I hear *realize* I think more of someone who up to a point didn't realize they had something or could do something. "He realized he could put his car in reverse rather than pushing it". Could just be me though :p

Comment: Yeah, I do as well.

Comment: It does legitimately mean taking something _potential_ and making it, er, _real_ ... but yes, it can be ambiguous

Comment: +1 The part about not realizing they had something is accurate, at least with the example the OP offered. Several characters in Star Wars who became Jedi had no idea initially that they had any powers.  I think this subtlety in the meaning makes it the best answer.

Comment: +1: Google Books - *"realised/realized his potential"*, 10,000 results; *"mastered his potential"*, 1 result.

Comment: +1 as I have seen realized used with exactly that connotation.

Comment: +1 since I agree that this is the correct usage. But I highly suspect that this usage will be understood incorrectly, especially (but not only!) by non-native speakers so in practice I’d err on the side of “mastered”.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "mastered" goes with "powers" and not "potential", while realized fits best with "potential" although it is also used in the same sense for "power".

Answer (score 12):

I think you're looking for the noun *command*:

> I have command of my power.
>
> I have full command of my powers.
>
> I have gained command of my power.

Answer (score 7):

Honed.  "I have honed my power".

> **honed** *past participle, past tense of hone (Verb)*
>
> Verb:  Sharpen with a whetstone. Make sharper or more focused or
>   efficient.

Answer (score 5):

Actualized or actualization! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-actualization

Comment: Words with ***-ize*** and ***-ization*** are lame excuses blocking the path to better words and true.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this hypothesis? The 40 people above who up-voted 'realize' seem to think differently!

Answer (score 4):

The word "channelled" could be used, with the implication that to channel something you must be in complete control of it.  For example:

> I have channelled my power

A slightly more flowery way to say the same thing is:

> I have become one with my power

Also, a term used in computing to mean "to have full and intimate knowledge of" is "grok" (see [Wikipedia - Grok](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grok)), so you could use:

> I have grokked my power

Although I would probably advise against using this unless you have a computing-based audience.

Comment: Just in case anyone didn't realize Scree was joking, Grok is a made up word from Heinlein's Hugo award wining Stranger in a Strange Land.

Comment: @JSWork actually Grok has been adopted (like so many Sci-Fi terms) by the IT community. As Scree mentioned if you're in a room full of geeks, grok is the PERFECT word to convey the meaning.

Comment: Grok is more about understanding than controlling.

Comment: I agree with @Sam, although my first thought upon reading the question was also “grok”. But it’s the wrong word here, it means something else.

Comment: I reluctantly agree with @sam.  Absolute control cannot exist without complete understanding, but complete understanding does not necessarily imply absolute control.

Comment: @LordScree Very true. E.g. We might have almost complete knowledge of how gravity works, but we cannot control it.

Answer (score 3):

How about : "I have **tamed** my Power"

Answer (score 0):

I have **perfected** my powers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for **encompassed**?  It seems to apply to the "how the world works" example a bit more than the other suggestions in that it denotes both mastery and understanding. It also sounds a bit like something a Jedi might say.

Comment: Hmmm... "I have encompassed my full potential..." I kind'a like that.